# QgisGeoJSONExportPlugin won't install

Tags: qgis-plugins, geojson

I'm trying to download and install the Plugin "QgisGeoJSONExportPlugin" I downloaded from the "QGIS Python Plugins Repository", since I couldn't find on the "manage and install plugins" window.

So I downloaded it and added the folder in the "plugins" in the C: Directory
C:\Users\jan\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins

I didn't get an error message but the folders font color is green which I have never seen before. And even after adding the plugin in my Directory it's not in my list of installed plugins.

has anyone any idea what the problem might be?

Comment: Latest commit to the plugin is `8db726c on Jul 14 2015`. I guess it is not updated to work on QGIS 3. Why do you want it? For making it easier to send GeoJSON into external service, or?

Comment: Thanks, you are right.
To convert my layer into GeoJSON... but I realiesed that I can do that simply by saving the layer as GeoJSON